# Wrong version of access token (expect V2 , received V1)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I am trying to register users from the Azure Active directory using @azure/msal-angular, to be more precise  I tried the following [tutorial](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular10-sample-app)

Those are the changes I have made to the project

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: 'my_real_client_id,
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_real_tenant_id',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}

  export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
  protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:5000/', ['profile']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
```

The problem is that MsalInterceptor adds **V1** token to the URL for the request to my API which expects **V2**.

Azure is configured to accessTokenAcceptedVersion: **2**

I can provide more information if needed

**Update**

In my case, the problem was due to the scopes specified, both API for  **"user.read"** and **"profile"** require V1 accessToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have resolved the issue, I would like to clarify more details.

In fact it's not the permissions "user.read" and "profile" require V1 accessToken. The actual reason is that:

Access Tokens versions are determined by the configuration of your **application/API** in the manifest. You have to change the accessTokenAcceptedVersion part of the manifest to 2 if you want a V2 access token. This is also the reason why you cannot control what version of the access token you will get from your **client application** when you request an access token.

We can't modify the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` from Microsoft Graph side.

So the conclusion is that an access token for MS Graph and those are always V1 access token.

Comment: any idea why I would have the same problem even if my app registration has accessTokenAcceptedVersion configured to 2 on the manifest ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. If the manifest can define the version as V2, why is the conclusion that the MS Graph token is always a V1 access token?

Comment: I have accessTokenAcceptedVersion 2 in the manifest. Postman return V2 token but MSAL returns V1 token which results in 401 for Azure Function call.

Comment: @Andre are you able to figure it out why it is behaving like that. i am also facing same issue

Comment: @vijayboli I think the problem was the permission. I did not need user.read so i removed that and then a V2 token was returned.